# Arithmetic Operations in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Trying to make a simple operation with ansible. The problem is that i need to use two diffenet values from tow different variables

the simple substraction code is:

```
- name: get the fact
  set fact:
     first_count: {{ 5 - 3 }}
```

the expected result is 2 but what i try to achieve is:

```
 - name: get the fact
   set fact:
      first_count: {{ {{ variable }} - {{ another_variable }} }}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this with Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it this way:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    first_var: 5
    second_var: 3

  tasks:
    - name: do the math
      set_fact:
        first_count: "{{ first_var - second_var }}"

    - name: print results
      debug:
        var: first_count
```

result will be:

```
TASK [print results] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "first_count": "2"
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. wil try that one